# How do I interate through a paired list when using map and lambda?

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, lambda

I'm stuck on how to iterate through a paired list while i'm using the map and lambda functions. I want to create a series of  histograms based on a central location and the distances of selected locations (x,y) to the center  and the number of times a particular distance appears, but I keep getting an index out of range error and I don't understand why. I'm not sure how to iterate through locations where I  need to specify which two values out of it. The whole thing works except the n part.

Sorry for not being clearer, the locations=numpy.array((x,y)) are locations from a boolean array that produces specific locations that I wanted to test instead of for whole array.  The values (x,y) produced are a two row array where the values I want are paired column-wise. The code before this was:

```
     def detect_peaks(data):
        average=numpy.average(data)*2
        local_max = data > average
        return local_max

    (x,y) = numpy.where(detect_peaks(data))

    for test_x in range(0, 8):
       for test_y in range(0,8):
          distances=[]
          locations=numpy.array((x,y))
          central=numpy.array((test_x,test_y))
          [map(lambda x1: distances.append(numpy.linalg.norm(locations[(x1,0),  (x1,1)]-central)), n) for n in locations]
          histogram=numpy.histogram(distances, bins=10)
```

I'll rewrite the map/lambda function and come back. Thanks!

Comment: Your `locations=numpy.array((x,y))`, what are `x` and `y`? Float values, arrays or something else?

Comment: Wow that's hard to read. You lambda function is too complicated. It will be easier to debug if you use a named function and spread it out over a few lines

Comment: @gnibbler, That lambda is not the best code, but basically that line is to fill the list `distance` with a distance measure to `central`, one each for each element in `locations`.The index error must originate from this line from slicing of `locations`. So it is important to know what `x` and `y` are.

Comment: @CTZhu, That's an understatement, it's terrible code. If you just fix this bug and leave the code in this state, the next bug will also be harder to find than it needs to be.

Comment: @CTZhu They are float values.

Comment: @gnibbler, I agree, but first we need to know what the intention is and then fix it. user1949752, do take a look: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html , it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? `x` and `y` are arrays of `int`, not `float`.
Not that I like the double `for` loops, they should be replaced with a more vectorized algorithm, but to keep the change minimal and high light the problematic line, here is it:

```
>>> a2
array([[ 0.92607265,  1.26155686,  0.31516174,  0.91750943,  0.30713193],
       [ 1.0601752 ,  1.10404664,  0.67766044,  0.36434503,  0.64966887],
       [ 1.29878971,  0.66417322,  0.48084284,  1.0956822 ,  0.27142741],
       [ 0.27654032,  0.29566566,  0.33565457,  0.29749312,  0.34113315],
       [ 0.33608323,  0.25230828,  0.41507646,  0.37872512,  0.60471438]])
>>> numpy.where(detect_peaks(a2))
(array([0, 2]), array([1, 0]))
>>> def func1(locations): #You don't need to unpack the numpy.where result.
    for test_x in range(0, 4):
       for test_y in range(0, 4):
          locations=numpy.array(locations)
          central=numpy.array((test_x,test_y))
          #Vectorization is almost always better.
          #Be careful, iterate an array means iterate its rows, so, transpose it first.
          distances=map(numpy.linalg.norm, (locations-central.reshape((2,-1))).T)
          histogram=numpy.histogram(distances, bins=10)
          print 'cental point:', central
          print 'distance lst:', distances
          print histogram
          print '-------------------------'
```

And the result:

```
>>> func1(numpy.where(detect_peaks(a2)))
cental point: [0 0]
distance lst: [1.0, 2.0]
(array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([ 1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7, 1.8,  1.9,  2. ]))
-------------------------
cental point: [0 1]
distance lst: [0.0, 2.2360679774997898]
(array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([ 0.        ,  0.2236068 ,  0.4472136 ,  0.67082039,  0.89442719, 1.11803399,  1.34164079,  1.56524758,  1.78885438,  2.01246118,         2.23606798]))
-------------------------#and more
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this:

```
def detect_peaks(arrayfinal):
    average=numpy.average(arrayfinal)
    local_max = arrayfinal > average
    return local_max

def dist(distances, center, n):
   distance=numpy.linalg.norm(n-center)
   distances.append(distance)

def histotest():
   peaks = numpy.where(detect_peaks(arrayfinal))
   ordered= zip(peaks[0],peaks[1])
   for test_x in range(0, 2048):
        for test_y in range(0,2048):
            distances=[]
            center=numpy.array((test_x,test_y))
            [dist(distances, center, n) for n in ordered]
            histogram=numpy.histogram(distances, bins=30)
            print histogram
```

It appears to work, but I like yours better.